# Permission denied while uploading a file

Tags: php

I am using this code to upload a document to my server.

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}else{
echo getcwd().'<br>';
echo "Upload in file named: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
$info = pathinfo($_FILES['userFile']['name']);
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$target = 'upload/100.'.$ext;
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target);
}

?>
```

I am getting these error message:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(C:\Inetpub\vhosts\api.cutm.ac.in\httpdocs\UploadMarks\upload\100.docx) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\api.cutm.ac.in\httpdocs\UploadMarks\uploadFile.php on line 14
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'C:\Windows\Temp\phpF64C.tmp' to 'C:\Inetpub\vhosts\api.cutm.ac.in\httpdocs\UploadMarks\upload\100.docx' in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\api.cutm.ac.in\httpdocs\UploadMarks\uploadFile.php on line 14

What am I doing wrong? What changes do I need in my code? Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that your folder is not having write permission. And because of that it is not uploading the file.

You have to give it write permission. You can also use [chmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) for giving write permission to that folder.

Also check who is having that write permission for that folder. When you upload the file from code it is uploaded as `Other` user.

[More info](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/filepermissions.html)

Comment: How did that work, it looks like he is running this on Windows?

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur:You can see the error message and it is self explanatory that the server is on windows.

Comment: @Dibya - I'm confused why you are telling him to use `chmod` if it's a windows box?

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur: I have not used `chmod` and I am not telling anybody to use `chmod` may be Yogesh wanted to add few extra details. I have never used `chmod` frankly I haven't visited the link too. The problem was solved when I granted full control so I didn't bother about the extra info he provided. Still these details might help next visitors.

Comment: @Dibya - My mistake, I was asking Yogesh why he is telling you to use `chmod` on Windows since it's a linux command.  No worries!

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur: Thanks for pointing out. When Yogesh will look at these comments may be he will edit the answer.